# Concatenate the row values after join

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to concatenate the row values after joining Table1 and table2.

Table 1:

```
-----
Col1     
------
  1      
  2
```

Table 2:

```
-----------------
Col1         Col2
-----------------
 1             A
 1             B
 1             C
 2             D
 2             E
 2             F
```

Desired Result:

```
-----------------
Col1         Col2
-----------------
 1          A,B,C
 2          D,E,F
```

Comment: which one you are using SQL SERVER ?? or MYSQL ??

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: Check this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table #table1(
    col1 int
)
create table #table2(
    col1 int,
    col2 char(1),
)
insert into #table1
select 1 union all 
select 2

insert into #table2
select 1, 'A' union all
select 1, 'B' union all
select 1, 'C' union all
select 2, 'D' union all
select 2, 'E' union all
select 2, 'F'


select
    col1,
    col2 = 
        stuff((
            select
                ', ' + t2.col2
            from #table2 t2
            where
                t2.col1 = t1.col1
            group by t2.col2
            for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'
        ), 1, 2, '')
from #table1 t1

drop table #table1
drop table #table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql:

```
SELECT group_concat(table2.col2) FROM 
   table2 JOIN table1 ON table1.col1 = table2.col1 
GROUP BY table2.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor as the following cod.

checked for syntax only

```
create table #Desired_Result(col1 int,col2 varchar(20))
DECLARE cur cursor FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR
 SELECT  col1,col2

DECLARE @d int
declare @l varchar(20)

declare @str1 varchar(30)=''
declare @str2 varchar(30)=''
OPEN cur
 FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @d,@l
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
 BEGIN 
if @d=1
set @str1=@str1+@l+','
else
if @d=2
set @str2=@str2+@l+','
FETCH NEXT FROM cur  INTO @d,@l
END
@str1=substring(@str1,1,len(@str1)-1)
@str2=substring(@str2,1,len(@str2)-1)
insert into #Desired_Result values (col1,col2)(1,@str1)
insert into #Desired_Result values (col1,col2)(2,@str2)

select * from #Desired_Result

Close  cur 
DEALLOCATE cur
```